# Inserting Duplicate data after confirmation with a dialog box

Tags: javascript, php

When Duplicate is data checked and the confirmation box apears I want to insert data when I press the ok button.

When I press the cancel button data should not be insert in DB.

How can I do this? Here is what I did so far:

```
<?php
            //insert data to database

            $category=Null;
            $model=Null;
            $part=Null;
            $remarks=Null;
            $partcode=Null;
            $partnumber=Null;
            $user=$_SESSION['login_user'];

            //Recive data from form
            if(isset($_POST['category'])){$category = $_POST['category'];}
            if(isset($_POST['model'])){$model = $_POST['model'];}
            if(isset($_POST['part'])){$part= $_POST['part'];}
            if(isset($_POST['remarks'])){$remarks = $_POST['remarks'];}
        //Check Duplicate Data From DB  
        $check="Select * From part Where Category='$category' and Model='$model' and PartName='$part'";
        $checkrun=mysqli_query($conn,$check);
        $checkrow=mysqli_num_rows($checkrun);
        if($checkrow>0){
            echo "<script>confirm('Duplicate Data! Click OK to Add & Cancel to Edit')</script>";
        }

        //Make Part Number  
        $maxPartQry="Select max(PartCode) FROM part";
        $maxPartRun=mysqli_query($conn,$maxPartQry);
        $maxpart=mysqli_fetch_array($maxPartRun);
        $partcode=$maxpart[0]+1;
        $invID = str_pad($partcode,6,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $partnumber=$model."-".$part."-".$invID;
        $product;


        //Insert Query For inserting data in DB
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `part` (`ID`, `PartCode`, `PartNumber`, `Category`, `Model`, `PartName`, `Remarks`, `Date`, `Name`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$partcode', '$partnumber', '$category', '$model', '$part','$remarks', NOW(), '$user');";
        if(($category != Null) ){
        $insert=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        if($insert){
            echo "<script>window.alert('New Part No. ".$partnumber." is Genrated Successfully!!')</script>";

        }
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: where is your codes ?
where is your mysql syntax ?

Comment: And what is your question - write the code for me?

Comment: Is this a joke? You didn't even format your code. And where's the question?

Comment: How to formate the code i directly coping the code from editor

Comment: Joshua Bakker Please guide me

Comment: I did it for you, but is seems you deleted it.

Comment: any body can help me...................

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that different pieces of code are executed at different locations. Eg:

- SQL queries are executed on the server side
- Alert / confirmation boxes are executed on the client side (web browser)
- Code for what is executed on the client side is generated on the server side

So multiple requests towards the server are needed if you wish to implement a scenario such as:

1. User posts data to the server
2. Server responds that data are duplicates (and returns script code for user confirmation)
3. Confirmation code is executed, user accepts the insertion of a duplicate
4. Confirmation is sent towards the server or data are posted again with the addition of a "accept duplicate" flag (typically, if server is stateless).
5. Server receives the confirmation / second post request, identifies it should accept duplicates, and perform the corresponding SQL query for insertion.

Steps 1, 3, 4 happen on the client side. Steps 2, 5 happen on the server side

In the case the user cancels, then server side code just skips the second post request.

So, you need extra code on the server side to differentiate the two requests (Is this a confirmation request? or Should duplicates be allowed?), and adapt its behavior accordingly. And you need extra code on the client side to generate the second request if user confirms that a duplicate should be inserted.

Of course, all of this would be even cleaner if client-side code was static rather than generated at server-side (google REST HTTP interfaces, for instance) but I fear that explaining this would only confuse you at the present time.